# gulp/uglify: odd property undefined errors

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I'm new to gulp, and am running into an odd problem. Sometimes, after prepping my site via gulp, an entity defined in a javascript file can't be found when a minimized version of my javascript files is used by a site. Or I'll get odd errors about not being able to read properties of undefined entities.

Other times the site runs fine. I haven't been able to see any patterns of when it fails and when it doesn't.

I've also noticed that excluding a javascript file from the uglification process can cause a similar kind of error to appear in a file which previously did not show any problems after uglification.

Here's my gulp file:

```
/// <binding Clean='clean' />
"use strict";

var gulp = require( "gulp" );
var rimraf = require( "rimraf" );
var concat = require( "gulp-concat" );
var cssmin = require( "gulp-cssmin" );
var uglify = require( "gulp-uglify" );
var mainBowerFiles = require( 'main-bower-files' );
var filter = require( "gulp-filter" );
var less = require( 'gulp-less' );
var path = require( 'path' );
var coffee = require( 'gulp-coffee' );
var rename = require( 'gulp-rename' );
var sequence = require('gulp-sequence');

// paths should generally be simple folder links
// wildcard and glob specifications should be added to 
// these as needed by a particular situation
var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};

paths.js = path.join(paths.webroot, 'js');
paths.css = path.join(paths.webroot, 'css');
paths.lib = path.join( paths.webroot, "lib" );
paths.repos = './repos/';

var chartPaths = [
    path.join( paths.js, 'chart/**/*.js' ),
    path.join( paths.js, 'chart-support/**/*.js' ),
    path.join( paths.js, 'data/**/*.js' ),
    path.join( paths.js, 'layout/**/*.js' ),
    path.join( paths.lib, 'ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.js' ),
    path.join( paths.lib, 'oms/lib/*.js' ),
];

var repoPaths = [
    path.join( paths.repos, 'oms', 'lib/*.js' ),
];

// primary tasks
//
// these are roughly in the sequence which should be followed when
// prepping the project. In particular, minimization should not
// be run until after all bower and subrepository management
// has been done
gulp.task( 'all', sequence( 'clean:lib', 'bower', 'repos', 'clean', 'min' ) );
gulp.task( "bower", sequence("bower:js-css", "bower:less") );
gulp.task( "repos", sequence("repos:coffee", "repos:js") );
gulp.task( "clean", sequence("clean:js", "clean:css") );
gulp.task( "min", sequence("min:chart-js", "min:css") );

// cleaning tasks
//
// delete all minimized javascript files in the js folder of wwwroot
gulp.task( "clean:js", function ( cb ) {
    rimraf( path.join( paths.js, '**/*.min.js' ), cb );
});

// delete all minimized css files in the css folder of wwwroot
gulp.task( "clean:css", function ( cb ) {
    rimraf( path.join( paths.css, '**/*.min.js' ), cb );
});

// delete lib folder of wwwroot
gulp.task( "clean:lib", function ( cb ) {
    rimraf( paths.lib, cb );
} );

// bower tasks
// 
// move bower-maintained javascript files into js folder of wwwroot
gulp.task( "bower:js-css", function () {
    var f = filter( ['**/*.js', '**/*.css'] );
    return gulp.src( mainBowerFiles(), { base: "./bower_components" } )
        .pipe( f )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.lib ) );
} );

// move bower-maintained css files into css folder of wwwroot
gulp.task( 'bower:less', function () {
    return gulp.src( './less/*.less' )
        .pipe( less( {
            paths: [
                './bower_components/bootstrap/less/'
            ]
        }) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.css ) );
} );

// subrepository compilation tasks
//
// compile coffee scripts into js files in the repos directory
gulp.task( "repos:coffee", function () {
    return gulp.src( path.join( paths.repos, '**/*.coffee' ), { base: paths.repos } )
        .pipe( coffee() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( function ( file ) {
            return file.base;
        } ) );
} );

// move repo javascript files into js folder of wwwroot
gulp.task( "repos:js", function () {
    return gulp.src( repoPaths, { base: './repos' } )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( paths.lib ) );
} );

// minimizing tasks
gulp.task( "min:chart-js", function () {
    return gulp.src( chartPaths )
        .pipe( concat( path.join(paths.js, 'chart.min.js' ) ) )
        .pipe( uglify() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( "." ) );
} );

gulp.task( "min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src( [path.join( paths.css, '**/*.css' ), "!" + path.join( paths.css, '**/*.min.css' )], { base: paths.css } )
        //.pipe( concat( path.join(paths.css, 'site.min.css') ) )
        .pipe( cssmin() )
        .pipe( rename( function ( path ) {
            path.basename += '.min';
            return path;
        }) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest(paths.css) );
} );
```

Since none of the files are all that big it won't be a huge problem if I have to forego uglification. But I'd like to figure out what I'm doing wrong before I get involved with a bigger project.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the JS file to see what's going on? You can "unminify" JS with Chrome dev tools "pretty print." As a total guess, if you're missing a semicolon and using concat() you can get some errors.

Comment: Great suggestion! It prompted me to find a javascript linter -- I settled on jsHint -- and analyze me codebase...which was littered with missing semicolons. I had no idea that javascript would execute in a browser context with those kinds of errors.

Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem. But it at least gave me a new attack surface to pursue. So again, thanx!!

Comment: Check out Eslint and set the option in the config file for missing semicolons. Then you can run it on your JavaScript files with `--fix` and it will add all the missing semicolons for you http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface